# MongoDB Atlas failed to connect to server on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect MongoDb Atlas from my `node.js` app but it goes timeout and gives me the error which is mentioned on header.

I've already added my IP to **IP Whitelist**. Moreover, I've added my **local IP**, **public IP** and **0.0.0.0/0**
All these 3 IP could't help me.

Here is the code that I am connecting with to MongoDb Atlas:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
}).then(function () {
    console.log("Connected to DB");
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("ERROR : " + err.message);
});
```

Comment: Make sure firewall isn't blocking. And check you're really using "Database User" you created with its own password, and didn't mix up with your own username. Let me know.

Comment: @MatinSasan I am using ubuntu and I don't have a firewall. I have created a few different users and passwords and tried them. It is still not working.

Comment: Try to connect with MongoDB Compass. If you could, then the problem is from the code. Also what happened to me mostly was because of using VPN. Try connecting without any VPN/proxy, if you use any.